Problem creating dynamic routes in Remix with the folder convention
I was reading the docs and found this

Scaling Our general recommendation for scale is to make every route a
folder and put the modules used exclusively by that route in the
folder, then put the shared modules outside of routes folder
elsewhere. This has a couple benefits:
Easy to identify shared modules, so tread lightly when changing them
Easy to organize and refactor the modules for a specific route without
creating "file organization fatigue" and cluttering up other parts of
the app

So I decided to migrate all my routes to a folder structure, ending up like this
routes/
│
├── _index.tsx              
├── category/
│   ├── $categoryId.tsx   
├── completed/
│   ├── route.tsx          
├── login/
│   ├── route.tsx          
├── process_tasks/
│   ├── route.tsx  

They all seem to work except
/category/1

It says 404 not found
How would I solve the folder structure to make it work?
And on the other hand, why do I need to put _index.tsx with an underscore for "/" to work? If I simply put index.tsx it won't load anything.

The reason why '$categoryId.tsx' doesn't work is because in Remix V2 if you want to render a route inside a folder. It should have the name 'route.tsx'. Just like you did in the folder 'completed', 'login' and 'process'. So following the convention, the file '$categoryId.tsx' should be named 'route.tsx'. The folder 'category' should then have the name 'category.$categoryId'.
Your use case is also described in the example in the Remix documentation.

Folders for organization
Your question why index.tsx doesn't work but _index.tsx does, is also part of the Remix convention.

Basic routes
